# Matlab help: I am given a second order differential equation.I need to use matlab to find unit step response and impulse response?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, differential-equations

I have the second order differential equation

```
 d^2(y(t))/dt^2+ B1*d(y(t))/dt+ c1*y(t)=A1*x(t)
```

t is in seconds and is greater than 0.
A1, B1, C1 are constants that equal:

```
A1= 3.8469x10^6
B1= 325.6907
C1= 3.8469x10^6
```

This system is linear, time-invariant, and casual. The system is called H1. 
I want to use Matlab to compute and plot the impulse response function h1(t) and the unit step response function g1(t) of this system.

Comment: Do you have the system identification toolbox or the control system toolbox?  This can be done in a couple lines if you do.  If not, then I think you need to use an ODE solver.

Comment: If you are interested in the analytical results, I found wolfram alpha  a nice way to quickly try things.  ex: http://bit.ly/RwxoNK

Answer (score 0):

There is quite the nifty function called dsolve in MATLAB
It takes in a string as its argument (similar to ezplot). You will probably have to manually type in your constants. But it will then solve the DE.

Typically these outputs, especially one like this will be nasty, so I recommend using the pretty function, to at least attempt to make it readable.

try typing:

help dsolve

into matlab and see what you get :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dsolve to find the impulse response, but the problem you solve is slightly different than the ODE.

The impulse response is a free response to an impulse at n-1, where n is the order of the ode. You want to solve for y(0)=0, dy/dt=1, with x = 0 (no forcing).

Here's how you could do that with MATLAB.

```
% // symbolic variables
syms y(t) x(t)

% // these could be symbolic as well
A1= 3.8469E6
B1= 325.6907
C1= 3.8469E6

% // so that you can pass an argument to diff(y)
Dy = diff(y)

% // symbolically solve
ySol = dsolve(diff(diff(y,t),t)+B1*diff(y,t)+C1*y-A1*0,y(0)==0,Dy(0)==1)

% // use five digits only (shortens the result)
digits(5)
ySol = vpa(ySol)

% // show a human readable result
pretty(ySol)

% // solve by replacing the symbol t with the numerical value
f = @(t) subs(ySol, 't', t)

% // plot the function.  note you can analytically know a better range 
% // from A1, B1, C1, but I leave that to you
ezplot(f, [0 .06])
```

---

[image: Result]

---

[image: Plot]

A better route, imho, is to use the analytical solution for the impulse response to a second order ODE.  There are many notes on this readily found with a search (such as [these notes](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/me451/jchoi/2007/handouts/ME451_S07_lecture17.pdf)).

For the step response, you could go into convolution integrals... but the the above should help with using the ode solver in doing so.